# AWK fast command?

Tags: bash, performance, awk

File1.csv

```
3398710422,5000,1,180000,1,,1
3301280335,801,1,0.0732,2,,
3398765402,8010,1,0.1,2,,
3398710132,801,1,1.2078,2,,
3301280033,801,1,0.0366,2,,
3201070157,7030,1,100,1,,13
3398772988,6000,1,150,2,,6
3201070157,7040,1,322122547200,1,,11
3398710122,7010,1,262076027,1,,1
3398710122,7020,1,209647227,1,,1
3201070200,7070,1,64424509440,1,,
3310080030,801,1,0.4392,2,,
```

File2.csv

```
1,3398710422,7679001,
13,3201070157,107363269,Product1
11,3201070157,107363269,Product1
1,3398710122,115615379,
6,3398772988,178969511,Product2
1,3398710212,214848153,
1,3398772987,232064121,
4,3202120151,323408705,Product3
1,3241000312,334663103,
1,3398710317,354231059,
3,3291010100,410449509,Product4
6,3261000217,428276109,Product5
5,3398700981,458493983,Product6
1,3398710222,466435383,
```

My_output.csv

```
3398710422,5000,1,180000,1,,1,
3301280335,801,1,0.0732,2,,,
3398765402,8010,1,0.1,2,,,
3398710132,801,1,1.2078,2,,,
3301280033,801,1,0.0366,2,,,
3201070157,7030,1,100,1,,13,Product1
3201070157,7040,1,322122547200,1,,11,Product1
3398710122,7010,1,262076027,1,,1,
3398710122,7020,1,209647227,1,,1,
3398772988,6000,1,150,2,,6,Product2
3202120151,2000,2,100,1,,4,Product3
3291010100,2000,2,100,1,,3,Product4
3261000217,2000,2,100,1,,6,Product5
3398700981,2000,2,100,1,,5,Product6
3201070200,7070,1,64424509440,1,,,
3310080030,801,1,0.4392,2,,,
```

So in short terms where
(1st position from file1.csv is equal with 2nd positions from File2.csv)
and
(7th position from file1.csv is equal with 1st position from file2.csv)

I need to paste in File1.csv the 4th position from File2.csv (if 4th position is empty just put a comma)

Since these 2 csv files have more than 200k rows I need to do the matching in a faster way. My awk command that is reading line by line it is very slow.

I tried this

```
cat File1.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS="," } {if ($7=="") {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","","} else {cmd = "product.sh "$1" "$7""; while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {split(result, array, ",")} {if (($7==array[1] && $1==array[2])) { print $0","array[4] } else {print $0","}} close(cmd);}}' > My_output.csv
```

product.sh script is

```
array=`grep "$2, $1" File2.csv | sed 's/< //g;s/ >//g;s/>//g;s/ //g;s/<NULL//g'`
echo $array
```

Thanks in advance.
A.

Comment: You're calling a shell script from awk and so spawning a subshell for every input line where $7 is null. That'll take a very long time - don't do that. Just implement the contents of that `product.sh` script directly in awk instead and your whole script will probably run in under 1 second.

Comment: how do you go from 12 lines in `File1.csv` to 16 lines in the expected output? if we're not supposed to generate 4 new rows then please verify that your expected output corresponds to the sample inputs provided in the question

Comment: are the first 2 fields from `File2.csv` guaranteed to be unique, or can these two combined fields show up more than once in `File2.csv`

Comment: That s why I posted this here. :) I m sure that I can construct a single awk command will be faster. At the moment 200k rows I process in like 20 minutes :|

Comment: @markp-fuso file1.csv and file2.csv have different number of rows

Comment: There's a million questions on this forum for how to merge 2 files, which it sounds like is all you need to do, and they all have basically the same answer (look for scripts that look like `awk 'NR==FNR{a[something]=something else; next}...' file1 file2`) so please just have a look around and pick the one that works best for you.

Comment: How is the line (in `My_output.csv`) `3301280335,801,1,0.0732,2,,,` produced? There is no line in `File2.csv` that matches the `3301280335`.

Comment: that's not my question; we should be able to take the two sample sets of input (`File1.csv` and `File2.csv`) and generate the desired output (`My_output.csv`); you have rows in `My_output.csv` that don't show up in `File1.csv`, eg, `3291010100` is missing from `File1.csv` but shows up in `My_output.csv` ... how are we supposed to generate this 'new' row in `My_output.csv`? Please update the contents of `My_output.csv` to insure they match with the samples provided from `File1.csv` and `File2.csv`

Comment: Rewrite "product.sh" in AWK so it's within same one AWK script. But, maybe just use `join`? `more than 200k rows` let's say 200000 per 50 bytes per line = that's only 10 megabytes. It's small.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- `File2.csv`: the combination of the 1st and 2nd fields is unique

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }

# 1st file:

FNR==NR { map[$1,$2]=$4; next }                              # use 1st and 2nd fields as indices in array, save 4th field

# 2nd file: 

        { $(NF+1)= ( ($7,$1) in map) ? map[$7,$1] : "" }     # create new field (NF+1) based on existences of 7th and 1st fields as indices in array, otherwise leave blank

1                                                            # print current line from 2nd file
' File2.csv File1.csv                                        # File2.csv is processed first
```

Sans comments:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR { map[$1,$2]=$4; next }
        { $(NF+1)= ( ($7,$1) in map) ? map[$7,$1] : "" }
1
' File2.csv File1.csv
```

Variation where we combine the last 2 lines of code:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==NR { map[$1,$2]=$4; next }
        { print $0, ($7,$1) in map ? map[$7,$1] : "" }
' File2.csv File1.csv
```

This generates:

```
3398710422,5000,1,180000,1,,1,
3301280335,801,1,0.0732,2,,,
3398765402,8010,1,0.1,2,,,
3398710132,801,1,1.2078,2,,,
3301280033,801,1,0.0366,2,,,
3201070157,7030,1,100,1,,13,Product1
3398772988,6000,1,150,2,,6,Product2
3201070157,7040,1,322122547200,1,,11,Product1
3398710122,7010,1,262076027,1,,1,
3398710122,7020,1,209647227,1,,1,
3201070200,7070,1,64424509440,1,,,
3310080030,801,1,0.4392,2,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach based **only** on column 1 of *File1.csv* and column 2 of *File2.csv*

```
% awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{arr[$2]=$4; next} {print $0","arr[$1]}' File2.csv File1.csv
3398710422,5000,1,180000,1,,1,
3301280335,801,1,0.0732,2,,,
3398765402,8010,1,0.1,2,,,
3398710132,801,1,1.2078,2,,,
3301280033,801,1,0.0366,2,,,
3201070157,7030,1,100,1,,13,Product1
3398772988,6000,1,150,2,,6,Product2
3201070157,7040,1,322122547200,1,,11,Product1
3398710122,7010,1,262076027,1,,1,
3398710122,7020,1,209647227,1,,1,
3201070200,7070,1,64424509440,1,,,
3310080030,801,1,0.4392,2,,,
```